# How to change the TextArea text when a button is clicked with the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to change the text area each time I press the button to by getting the value of result in my controller

This is my model

```
public class GenerateModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string MonsterLevelId { get; set; }
    public string NbMosnterId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonsterLevel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> NbMonster { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
}
```

This is the view

```
<dl class="row">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NbMonster)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.NbMosnterId, new SelectList(Model.NbMonster, "Value", "Text"))
    </dt>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MonsterLevel)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MonsterLevelId, new SelectList(Model.MonsterLevel, "Value", "Text"))
    </dt>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.result, Model.result)
</dl>
<input type="submit" value="generate" class="btn" />
```

and this is my controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new GenerateModel
    {
        NbMonster = new[]
        {
             new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" },
             new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" }
        },
        MonsterLevel = new []
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" }
        }
    };

    return View(model);
}

public IActionResult generate(String MonsterLevel, String NbMonster)
{
    var model = new GenerateModel();

    model.result = ((Int32.Parse(MonsterLevel)) + (Int32.Parse(NbMonster))).ToString();
    return View(model);
}
```

Also when I click on the button  named generate, it active the function in the controller generate with the value NbMonster + MonsterLevel, do the function and return the result into the text area

Comment: Note related, but its just `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.result)` (remove the 2nd argument)

Comment: And its pointless extra overhead to use `new SelectList(..)` in the view to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.NbMosnterId, Model.NbMonster)` etc. and you should be using `@HtmlLabeFor(model => model.NbMosnterId)`

Comment: You are generating form controls for properties named `NbMosnterId` and `MonsterLevelId`, therefore the parameters in the controller method must match - i.e. public IActionResult generate(int NbMosnterId, int MonsterLevelId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code

```
Model

public class GenerateModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int MonsterLevelId { get; set; }
    public int NbMosnterId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonsterLevel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> NbMonster { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
}

Controller

    public ActionResult Index() 

            {
                var model = new GenerateModel
                {
                    NbMonster = new[]{
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" },
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" }
                    },
                    MonsterLevel = new[]{
                new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" }
                    }
                };

                return View(model);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Generate(GenerateModel model)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                model.result = (model.MonsterLevelId + model.NbMosnterId).ToString();
                model.NbMonster = new[]{
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" },
                 new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" }
                    };
                model.MonsterLevel = new[]{
                new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" }
                    };

                return View("Index", model);
            }

View



     @model WebApplication1.Models.GenerateModel


        @using (Html.BeginForm("Generate", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <dl class="row">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NbMonster)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.NbMosnterId, new SelectList(Model.NbMonster, "Value", "Text"))
            </dt>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MonsterLevel)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MonsterLevelId, new SelectList(Model.MonsterLevel, "Value", "Text"))
            </dt>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.result)

        </dl>
        <input type="submit" value="generate" class="btn" />
        }
```